# OTRS5 - Prevent error dialog on custom new phone ticket screen

Tags: otrs

I am currently customising an *OTRS5* installation and have created a new link to create a specific type of ticket, which preselects the queue and customer, and fills out the subject automaticlly. I am doing this using the following URL string:

```
index.pl?Action=AgentTicketPhone;Subaction=StoreNew;Dest=13%7C%7CInternal%3A%3APoC;TypeID=1;Subject=Cylance%20PoC%20Request;CustomerID=999;OTRSAgentInterface=Tyx6YwchDd2S6iDrydUSwpKjuyAcjbqR
```

However, I still want the user to enter a customer user manually but because I am not setting a customer user in the URL it is throwing an error that at least one customer user must be selected.

Does anyone know how to either prevent the error message from happening at all (ideally) or alternatively how I can set a customer user from the URL (as I tried `SelectedCustomerUser=*` and `PreSelectedCustomerUser=*)` but neither of them did anything.

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I managed to work it out myself. If you add `ExpandCustomerName=2;` to the URL string it no longer presents the error and lets the user add the CustomerUser themselves.